# Default values for querystring parameters, the Ruby way?

Tags: ruby

What's the Ruby way to do this?

```
if params[:month]
  @selected_month = params[:month].to_i
else 
  @selected_month = Time.now.month
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
@selected_month = (params[:month] || Time.now.month).to_i
```

the to_i could be a bit redundant on the end for Time.now.month, but it would eliminate the if/else logic